# the microsoft access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'Test'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, union-all

getting the following error in access 2010,

```
the Microsoft access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'Test'. 
Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.
```

when running,

```
SELECT 
      TEST.[CATEGORY CODE] AS CATEGORYCODE
    , TEST.[SAMPLE COMPOSITION] AS SAMPLECOMPOSITION
    , Sum(TEST.[WPI]) AS [SumOfWPI]
    , Sum(TEST.[Mean Freq Year Fav]) AS [SumOfMean Freq Year Fav] 
FROM 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM DATA1 
    WHERE DATA1.[CATEGORY CODE] IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT CODES.[CATEGORY CODE] 
            FROM CODES
        ) 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT * 
    FROM DATA2 
    WHERE DATA2.[CATEGORY CODE] IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT CODES.[CATEGORY CODE] 
            FROM CODES
        ) 
) AS TEST 
WHERE TEST.[COUNTRY] = 'UNITED STATES' 
    AND TEST.[SAMPLE COMPOSITION] IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT TEST.[SAMPLE COMPOSITION] 
        FROM TEST
    ) 
    AND TEST.[CATEGORY CODE] IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT CODES.[CATEGORY CODE] 
        FROM CODES
    ) 
GROUP BY TEST.[CATEGORY CODE], TEST.[SAMPLE COMPOSITION] 
ORDER BY TEST.[CATEGORY CODE];
```

I am creating a 4th table TEST using union all by clubbing 2 tables Data1 & Data2 and making sure only the records are for Category codes taken from Codes tables. Any ideas why its giving me this error?

if i remove this line which is a self-join to the table created by union all:
    AND TEST.[SAMPLE COMPOSITION] IN (SELECT DISTINCT TEST.[SAMPLE COMPOSITION] FROM TEST)

i am able to run the query....

Also, right now i have specified COUNTRY = "UNITED STATES". But how do i specify COUNTRY="<>UNITED STATES" OR COUNTRY= All Countries, so that i can get Totals for each?

right now i am doing multiple criteria Autofilters to achieve this, but it is taking 1.5 days as the data after clubbing the 2 tables is ~92000 records. So, trying access to achieve the same. If someone can help me, then i can send a sample file containing data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference TEST until it is created, and you're creating it as a result of the query.  You're going to have to do it with 2 queries, since you need all the results in your UNION ALL.

COUNTRY <> "UNITED STATES" will answer your second question.

Comment: i am sure there is a way to do it, instead of having 2 queries setup.
regarding my 2nd question, how do i show all the countries including United States?

Comment: All countries would be COUNTRY = *

Comment: can i have something like 
    WHERE COUNTRY LIKE ("*", "UNITED STATES", "<>UNITED STATES")
and get totals for each?

Comment: i guess no one has any idea.

Comment: Try doing something like:

 IIf([Country]="*","United States","<> United States") AS TestCol

And then you can group by that column.

Comment: In your SELECT statement AND in the GROUP BY statement.

Comment: i dont want an IIF condition which states IF Country is ALL, then total Country which are US, Else total Country which are non-US. What i want is Sums for Countries = *, US & Non-US.

Comment: The only way you're going to be able to group by (or sum) US and NON US is if you have a field that says which countries are US and which are NON US.  And the only way you're going to get that field is by putting an IIF statement in your query.